# Convert a matplotlib pie chart to plotly dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I am getting the following error, when I try to convert MatPlotLib generated pie chart to Plotly dictionary: *PlotlyEmptyDataError: Empty data list found. Make sure that you populated the list of data objects you're sending and try again.*

Indeed, if I execute *plotly_fig* (pls. see script bellow) I get data empty:

```
{'data': [],
 'layout': {'annotations'...etc.
```

I couldn't find limitations for pie charts, so I am not sure if I do something wrong?

```
    #import pylab 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl 
import plotly 
# Plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 7
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l = ax.pie([1,0.2, 0.3,0.1,0.4,7,50,35,5,2],#[0, 0.1, 0, 0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1],
           labels=("one","two","three made up sentences","four is also ther","five becomes a sentence","six it is","seven long", "eight long sent", "nine, as bla bel mo","ten is also short"),
            #labels=("","","","","","six it is","seven long", "eight long sent", "nine, as bla bel mo","ten is also short"),
            colors=("b","g","r","y", "b","g","r","y","g","black"),
            startangle =20,
            radius=1,
            explode = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2,  0.2, 0.2, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02 ],
            frame=True,   # Plot axes frame with the chart if true.
            labeldistance = 1.1 ) #returns a list of matplotlib.patches.Wedge objects
#l_in = ax.pie([1,0.2, 0.3,0.1,0.4,7,50,35,5,2],#[0, 0.1, 0, 0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1],
#            colors=("w","w","w","w", "w","w","w","w","w","w"),
#            startangle =20,
#            radius=0.4,
#            frame=True)   

l2 = ax.pie([1,0.2, 0.3,0.1,0.4,7,50,35,5,2],#[0, 0.1, 0, 0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1],
            colors=("r","g","b","w", "g","b","y","r","w","black"),
            explode = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2,  0.2, 0.2, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02 ],
            startangle =20,
            radius=1-0.7,
            frame=True)   # Plot axes frame with the chart if true.
ax.axis('equal')

plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(fig)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)    # help(go.Figure) -['data', 'frames', 'layout']
plotly.offline.iplot(plotly_fig, filename='test_MatPlotLib_modif_Plotly')
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it short, plotly's `mpl_to_plotly` is currently (as of August 2017) not able to convert pie charts.

The longer version: A matplotlib pie chart consists of `matplotlib.patches.Wedge` objects. Those are `matplotlib.patches.Patch`es. If `mpl_to_plotly` finds a patch, it will convert it to a path and assume that it is part of a bar chart. Since it isn't in this case, it will give up, throwing a warning *"I found a path object that I don't think is part of a bar chart. Ignoring."*. The produced figure will therefore not have any data and the error as in the question is thrown.

Comment: is there any related issue to solve this problem. Does Plotly maintainers acknowledge this bug? can we help? It would be great if there is an issue opened to follow up this further

Comment: @JustInTime First, it's not really a bug, it's rather an unimplemented feature. Given that the code throws a warning suggests that the developper is indeed aware about this feature missing. Since plotly is not community maintained as other true open source projects like matplotlib are, you cannot provide pull requests etc. to the source. But you may of course mention it on [community.plot.ly](https://community.plot.ly) and see what people have to say about it.

Comment: thanks for your response and excuse me if I misused the word Bug here. I will mention it in plot.ly community and see if I can help